# Как понять что ввод начался? с++

Tags: c++

Есть два потока, когда начинается ввод в одном требуется остановить другой поток, как понять что ввод в первом потоке начался.
Если использовать:

```
cin >> a[0]; 
b = true;
```

то после ввода первого символа требуется нажать enter, как этого избежать?
Возможно это можно сделать по-другому.

Желательно не использовать conio.h и windows.h тк работаюна os x.

Comment: OS X это mac (зачит \*nix)? Если так, то смотрите в [man select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)/[man poll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) что вам больше подойдет для обнаружения, когда в stdio  появился символ.

Comment: Достаточно функции ввода/вывода защитить критической секцией (std::mutex).